# Trying to compare text using for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, python-requests

I have various Brands URL in a dataframe which I have got using automated google search,I have split these URL into words and trying to compare the brand name and the manufacturer name with the URL to check if is correct or not(AS most companies have URL either based on their Brand name or their manufacturing company name)

```
try: 
              from googlesearch import search 
except ImportError: 
              print("No module named 'google' found") 


for i in search(Brand.get_attribute("innerHTML"), tld="com", num=15, stop=1, pause=2): 
    webaddresses.append(i)

for i in search(Manufacturer.get_attribute("innerHTML"), tld="com", num=15, stop=1, pause=2): 
    webaddresses.append(i)

for i in search(Brand.get_attribute("innerHTML") and Manufacturer.get_attribute("innerHTML"), tld="com", num=15, stop=1, pause=2): 
    webaddresses.append(i)

for i in search(Brand.get_attribute("innerHTML") and Manufacturer.get_attribute("innerHTML") and "Beverage", tld="com", num=15, stop=1, pause=2): 
    webaddresses.append(i)

webaddresses = pd.DataFrame(webaddresses)
webaddresses.rename(columns = {list(webaddresses)[0]:'URL'}, inplace=True)

splitting_gurl = webaddresses['URL'].str.split(r'[.\:/?=\-&]+', expand = True)




for i in range(len(splitting_gurl.index)):
    row = splitting_gurl.loc[[i]]    
    for j in range (0,5):
        if row[[j]] == str(Brand_check) or row[[j]] == str(Manufacturer_check):
            a=webaddresses.loc[[i]]
            print(a)
```

Following is the Error:-

```
 File "<ipython-input-124-0b002229b2b7>", line 4, in <module>
if row[[j]] == str(Brand_check) or row[[j]] == str(Manufacturer_check):

File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1576, in __nonzero__
.format(self.__class__.__name__))

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I just want my For  Loop and IF statement to run and compare the words.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/354577) (TL;DR: It's never okay.)

Comment: Rohit, please read the link I put in my first comment. You can't come here and demand that we help you urgently. It's not how things work. Daniel's edit to remove that from your title probably saved you from a ton of downvotes. Commenting that you need help every 5 minutes is just going to annoy people. We know you need help; that's why you asked a question.

Comment: Now, if you want help with your code it needs to accurately reflect your problem. The code you've posted will generate an `IndentationError`. Please [edit] your question and fix it. We're not going to guess which errors are relevant and which aren't. The easiest way to share code is to paste it into your question, then select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K. This will indent the whole block by four spaces so it's correctly formatted.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Chris, I will keep it in mind and apologizes to act unprofessionally from my side.

Comment: Okay, thanks for updating the question. This looks much better. It might be clear to somebody who knows Numpy, but unfortunately I don't. What is `splitting_gurl`? What are `Brand_check` and `Manufacturer_check`? What is `webaddresses`? If you can add a small amount of code to show that the question will be even more clear. Ideally, we'd like a [mcve].

Comment: webaddresses :- It is a dataframe consisting of URL's which I am extracting using automated google search
splitting_gurl- In this I have split all the URL present in webaddresses and have saved in their respective rows 

e.g - Suppose the given web address is saved at row number 1 :-https://stackoverflow.com/questions
In splitting_gurl it will be at the same place i.e row 1 but will have multiple columns consisting of words -"https" , "stackoverflow", "com" , "questions"
EVery word will be in different column, so that I can compare it with the Brand_check(which consists of brand name)

Comment: I'm still not totally clear what's going on, but what happens if you wrap `row[[j]]` in a call to `str()` in that line?

Comment: Or maybe with [`.astype(str)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use Fuzzywuzzy package in python , it compares the words on the basis of levenstein distance and penalizes it for either of the actions i.e Insertion of the alphabet ,deletion or replacement.